# Dart - Find all roots in a function

Tags: math, dart, equation

I am trying to find all roots [f(x) = 0] in a function. My current solution only works if they are spaced out enough and don't interfer with each other. (e.g. it works for x^2 - 2)

```
bool numberIsCloseToZero(num number){
  return (num.parse(number.abs().toStringAsFixed(1)) == 0.0) ? true : false;
}

List<num> calculateRoots(String function){

  num eval = 0.0;
  List<num> roots = [];

  for (num x = -10; x < 10; x += 0.1){
    eval = calculateYOfX(function, x);
    if (numberIsCloseToZero(num.parse(eval.toStringAsFixed(2)))){
      roots.add(x);
    }
  }
  return roots;
}
```

Obviously, this is due to my rounding. (e.g. the surrounding values of the root of x^2 are too close to zero, so it assumes they are roots as well). Do you think I should go through actually solving the equation instead of "brute forcing" the roots?

Thanks

Comment: This is a nice question but not really about Dart programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to put some restrictions on what is an allowable function, otherwise you have no hope.

For example without any restrictions you've no guarantee that there are is only a finite number of values (consider `f(x)=sin(x)` ), or even a finite number of values in a given interval (consider `f(x)=x sin(1/x)` ). Or even an infinity of connected zeros ( `f(x) = max(0,x)` )

And these cases are not even considered particularly pathological mathematical functions.

If you're willing to go down the path of requiring your function to be non-zero almost-everywhere, smooth, continuous and with bounded first and second derivatives  then I think you may be able to come up with a relatively simple algorithm that guarantees you get all zeros in a given finite region.

(I'd look for a subdivision based algorithm which recursively splits the region and determines strict bounds on each interval.)

We can derive an example algorithm for when the derivative is bounded by a known constant i.e. `|f'(x)| < D`. Note that if we evaluate `f` at some point `p` then for any other point `p+d` we can show that `f(p) - |d| D < f(p+d) < f(p) + |d| D`.

Using this we can consider root finding in an interval `[A,B]` - which we can write as `[p-d, p+d]` where `p=(A+B)/2`, `d=(B-A)/2`. Sample `f` at the mid-point to get `f(p)`. The minimum value `f` could take on the interval is `f(p) - d D` and the maximum value is `f(p) + d D`. We can only have a root in this interval if `f(p)-d D <= 0 <= f(p) +d D` which is equivalent to `|f(p)| < d D`.

If there can be no root in `[A,B]` we're done, otherwise we repeat on the two halves `[A,p]` and `[p,B]`. (some care needs to be taken in the case `f(p)=0` )

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get the roots of basic functions with bisection, which is completely fine in my case! Awesome answer btw.

Answer (score 3):

If you can find analytical solution - use it. It is possible for low-degree polynomial equations (like mentioned `x^2 - 2`).

In general case - you definitely have to learn numerical methods - in this case, [root finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm).

Start with [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) method or [Newthon's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) method. They allow to get more and more exact position of root at every step.